Compare two variances
I am reading this paper
I have difficulty understanding Section 6: A Linear Time Statistic and Test.
At the beginning, they claim that $\text{MMD}^2_l$ has higher variance than $\text{MMD}^2_u$ (we will see this explicitly later).' However, I don’t understand the reason, even after reading the remaining part
I guess it comes from those lines

Assume $0 < \mathbb{E}(h^2) < \infty$. Then $\text{MMD}_l^2$ converges in distribution to a Gaussian according to
$$m^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \text{MMD}_l^2 - \text{MMD}^2[\mathcal{F}, p, q] \right) \overset{D}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_l^2)$$
where
$$
\sigma_l^2 = 2 \left[ \mathbb{E}_{z, z'} h^2(z, z') - \left( \mathbb{E}_{z, z'} h(z, z') \right)^2 \right]$$
where we use the shorthand $\mathbb{E}_{z, z'} := \mathbb{E}_{z, z' \sim p \times q}$
The factor of 2 arises since we are averaging over only $\lfloor m/2 \rfloor$ observations. It is instructive to compare this asymptotic distribution with that of the quadratic time statistic $\text{MMD}_u^2$ under $\mathcal{H}_A$, when $m = n$. In this case, $\text{MMD}_u^2$ converges in distribution to a Gaussian according to
$$m^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \text{MMD}_u^2 - \text{MMD}^2[\mathcal{F}, p, q] \right) \overset{D}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_u^2)$$
where
$$
\sigma_u^2 = 4 \left( \mathbb{E}_z \left[ \left( \mathbb{E}_{z'} h(z, z') \right)^2 \right] - \left( \mathbb{E}_{z, z'} h(z, z') \right)^2 \right) \quad \text{(Serfling, 1980, Section 5.5)}.$$
Thus for $\text{MMD}_u^2$, the asymptotic variance is (up to scaling) the variance of $\mathbb{E}_z[h(z, z')]$, whereas for $\text{MMD}_l^2$ it is $\text{Var}_{z, z'}[h(z, z')]$

I am quite confused about how they can prove their statement. I hope you can explain it to me explicitly because I am relatively new to this field. Many thanks.

I see multiple assertions in this quotation.  What, then, are you referring to by "their statement"?

@whuber hello, as you can see in the paper, in section 6, they said that "While it is expected that $MMD^2_l$ has a higher variance than $MMD^2_u$
(as we will see explicitly later)"
But I don't understand why
